# rails "No route matches" even though it's in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have this form:

```
<% @softwares.each do |l| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= l.vendor %></td>
    <td><%= l.title %></td>
    <td><%= l.edition %></td>
    <td><%= l.amount %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'view', software_path %></td>

<% end %>
```

When i click on the view link i get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"softwares"}`

However when i run rake routes it does show up:

`software GET    /softwares/:id(.:format)      softwares#show`

and if i type it into the browser manually it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass software object in path because it's a member route
`<%= link_to 'view', software_path(l) %>`

Answer (score 0):

For RESTful resources you can just pass the resource:

```
link_to 'view', l
# => <a href="/softwares/1">view</a>
```